# Why is my crontab script not working?

Tags: cron

im trying to run a script stored in my home directory via crontab, but it's not working. The CRON log just says this every time it's running:

```
Sep  3 18:30:01 backup CRON[6778]: (root) CMD (/home/hannes/script > /tmp/yc.log)
Sep  3 18:30:01 backup CRON[6777]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/hannes/script > /tmp/yc.log
```

If I try to add the .sh file extension, it does not change anything.
The yc.log file stays empty.

This is the Script I'm trying to execute (Works fine if I run it manually):

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -r -p mnt/main-nas/PATH-TO-FILE mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
zip -r mnt/backup-nas/01/1.19_Test.`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.zip mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
rm -r mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: change `/home/hannes/script > /tmp/yc.log` to `/home/hannes/script > /tmp/yc.log 2>&1` to capture errors in the log file

Comment: Thank you! I misspelt the command for the log and so the logs didn't show up. With the help of the logs I was able to fix it! Wow I feel kinda bad, that it was such a simple mistake.

Comment: Instead of `zip -r mnt/backup-nas/01/1.19_Test.\`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S\`.zip mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server` use `zip -r mnt/backup-nas/01/1.19_Test.$(date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S).zip mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server`.  Try to avoid using backticks for subcommands and use `$(command)` instead.  Also, I don't know if it is a typo, but you are missing the `/` in front of the `mnt/`, it should be `/mnt/...`

Comment: The typo was exactly what was causing the problem! I'll edit the script so it doesn't use the backticks anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script *is* actually running... but it's erroring out somewhere.
And since you don't capture `stderr` output, stderr is sent via `cron` to the user who's running the script locally.  (And failing as well)

The root cause is this: your script only redirects `stdout` to files.  A lot of failing scripts and programs, however, use `stderr` to output their error messages.  You need to catch that by adding `2>&1` to the end of your command line that `cron` executes, which will also capture `stderr` and log errors to your file as well.

Because you didn't catch it previously, stderr was being delivered via mail to `root` - but because you don't have a local MTA (Mail Transfer Agent aka Local Mail Transport Protocol (LMTP) server) for local delivery, you got those cron errors.  With the `stderr` capture you will now see errors and why your script(s) haven't run properly.

Once you have the error output in your logs, you can further debug your script to determine what needs to be done to 'fix' things.

Answer (score 2):

So there were several issues. Firstly I forgot to add the `2>&1` end of the `/home/hannes/script > /tmp/yc.log` so that the log would actually get saved. And secondly I had a typo in my script, where I forgot the first slash in all of the paths. It went from this `home/hannes/...` to this `/home/hannes/...`.
I hope this helps other people having a similiar issue and thanks to everyone who replied :)

Comment: Okay this went quite wrong. I tried to close the question. My issue is solved. How do I close the question? Do I just delete it?

Comment: The green check mark ✅ indicates the correct answer. This is a question answer site. Others can post new answers. Since the accepted answer has 2 up votes, others have found that answer useful. For that reason I won't recommend you to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct and covers the stated question. However, the information provided in the question indicates an unrelated potential issue with this script that I feel is important to warn the OP about, and properly explaining it is too long for a comment, so I’m adding an answer specifically to cover that.

---

Aside from the logging issue, your arrangement also has a potentially nasty race condition. Because the script is always using the same directory for staging the files to be archived, if more than one instance of the script runs concurrently, then the first one run is likely to remove files that any subsequent instances are currently working on, leading to additional failures and most likely incomplete archives (because the files will disappear before `zip` can process them).

This can be resolved in one of two ways, either the script itself should use a per-invocation directory, or file locking should be used to prevent concurrent runs.

The first approach is much easier, you can just add the date to the directory you’re using. That would look something like this (note that this also ensures that `date` is only called once):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
now="$(date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S)"
cp -r -p mnt/main-nas/PATH-TO-FILE mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server/${now}
zip -r mnt/backup-nas/01/1.19_Test.${now}.zip mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server/${now}
rm -r mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server/${now}
```

The file locking approach is a bit more complicated, but arguably cleaner because it also ensures that you can’t accidentally swamp the system with multiple `zip` commands running at the same time. This involves using a command called `flock` (part of the `util-linux` package on Ubuntu and Debian, which will already be installed), and looks something like this (with comments to explain what’s going on):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# All of this gets run in a subshell so we can hold a file descriptor open
# for all the commands. We're using file descriptor 9 here, but any number
# higher than 2 will work.
(
    # This flock command is what actually takes the lock. The lock itself 
    # persists until the file descriptor is closed when the subshell exits.
    # The -x means it's an exclusive lock (so only one instance can hold it).
    # The -w says to try for that many seconds before failing if something
    # else is holding the lock (this is an important safety net to ensure you
    # don’t get a long queue of these scripts waiting to run).
    # The -n indicates which file descriptor to take the lock on.
    flock -x -w 30 -n 9 || exit 1
    cp -r -p mnt/main-nas/PATH-TO-FILE mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
    zip -r mnt/backup-nas/01/1.19_Test.`date +%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S`.zip mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
    rm -r mnt/backup-nas/01/temp/server
# And this line closes the subshell, and also sets the path to be used for
# the lock file by opening it as file descriptor 9 for the subshell. /run
# is generally the place you want to put stuff like this, because it will
# get cleaned up automatically every time the system reboots.
) 9> /run/backup-nas.lock
```

Comment: Isn't using the process ID (`$$`) an easier way to disambiguate than the date? (Also safer, as two invocations can be started within the same second — even within the same millisecond, if you include that — but they can't have the same PID.)